# MySQL - Returning values based on 2 fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a bit of an issue i was hoping someone could help me with.

I have a table ( messages ) that has the following columns

```
user_one
user_two
ip
time
user_one_deleted
user_two_deleted
```

So basically what i need to do is check to see if my id is in either the user_one or user_two fields .. if my id is found in the user_one field check to see if user_one_deleted = 0 then return the results, if it = 1 then skip it ..... if my id is found in the user_two field then check to see if the user_two_deleted = 0 then return results, if it = 1 then skip it.

I hope this makes sense, im trying to get my head around it but i dont have that much exp with MySQL.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Comment: `...WHERE \`user_one\`='$id' AND \`user_two_deleted\`=0` - Try and understand this and incorporate this into your code.

Comment: @zdhickman, that's only a partial solution.

Comment: @SurrealDreams ...correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   messages
WHERE ( user_one = yourid AND user_one_deleted = 0 )
   OR ( user_two = yourid AND user_two_deleted = 0 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Sounds doable to me.  Assuming the ID you want to check is stored in $id, this should work:

```
"SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE ( `user_one` = $id AND `user_one_deleted` = 0 )
    OR ( `user_two` = $id AND `user_two_deleted` = 0 );"
```

Run that query and you should have your results.